# Extract multiple decimal numbers from string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, extract, string-matching

I have a table in SQL Server Management Studio with columns containing ranges of numbers as strings. I am trying to find a way to extract the numeric values from the string and insert them into a new table.

For example, in the table I have the value `12.45% - 42.32%` as a string. I'd like to be able to get `12.45` and `42.32` and insert them into a new table with columns `min_percent` and `max_percent`.

I found several ways to extract a single numeric value from a string using SQL, and also tried modifying the function from [Extract numbers from a text in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629880/extract-numbers-from-a-text-in-sql-server) (which returns multiple integers, but not decimals), but so far I haven't been able to get it working. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is consistent, this should work fine, and has the added advantage of being easier on the eyes.  Also consider decimal if you're going for precision.

```
select
  cast(left(r, charindex('%', r) - 1) AS float) as minVal,
  cast(replace(right(r, charindex('-', r) - 1), '%', '') as float) AS maxVal
from ( select '22.45% - 42.32%' as r ) as tableStub
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is quite close. You just use numeric and add the point:

```
  with C as
  (
    select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as decimal(16,2)) as Number,
           stuff(s.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '') as Value
    from (select @String+' ') as S(Value)
      cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9,.]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)
      cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9,.]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)
    union all
    select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as decimal(16,2)),
           stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '')
    from C as S
      cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9,.]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)
      cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9,.]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)
    where patindex('%[0-9,.]%', S.Value) > 0
  )
  select Number
  from C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force approach using the string operations available in SQL Server:

```
with t as (
      select '12.45% - 42.32%'  as val
     )
select cast(SUBSTRING(val, 1, charindex('%', val) - 1) as float) as minval,
       cast(replace(substring(val, len(val) - charindex(' ', reverse(val))+2, 100), '%', '') as float) as maxval
from t
```