# extract text from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract text from the string `KWR/50X50X5/1.4301` between `/`, or `50x50x5` in `T-SQL`. I've tried using `Substing`, however, does not go to me.
Ultimately, I need to add the values (sum values) ​​in between `/` without character `x` (for example, `50 + 50 + 5 = 105`) I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010295/split-alpha-and-numeric-using-sql

Comment: KWR/--X--X--/1.4301 ...this will be fixed all the time?

Comment: Can be there `50X50X5X4X7`? Can you give all possible patterns?

Comment: It can be just as written . The principle is similar for all cases. So there may be more figures to sum , and between them x . Thanks for your response

Comment: Here is the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/5957

Comment: for example, PWPQ/80X20/1.4301 ,PWO/120/1.4404, PWOI/120x9x90x80/1.4404

Comment: you means all this data in one column?? if in different column then check this..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1fae/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT,  v VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'PWPQ/80X20/1.4301' ) ,
        ( 2, 'PWO/120/1.4404' ),
        ( 3, 'PWOI/120X9X90X80/1.4404' )


;WITH cte1 AS(SELECT id, SUBSTRING(v, 
                                   CHARINDEX('/', v) + 1, 
                                   CHARINDEX('/', v, CHARINDEX('/', v) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', v) - 1) AS v
             FROM @t),
      cte2 AS(SELECT id, CAST ('<X>' + REPLACE(v, 'X', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS v FROM  cte1)
SELECT id, SUM(Split.a.value('.', 'int')) AS v  
FROM  cte2 a CROSS APPLY v.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a)
GROUP BY id
```

Output:

```
id  v
1   100
2   120
3   299
```

First cte is for extracting value between `/`.
Second cte for casting those values to xml format.
The last statement is standard trick for transposing string with delimeter to separate rows.

Comment: great, did not mention that I have a table in which the specified text (code ) . I would like to do a select from table and point the id of the record and the query will return me the value of that figured out . Sory for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(firstpart,1,CHARINDEX('/',firstpart)-1)
from 
(select 
substring(pattern,
                 CHARINDEX('/',pattern)+1,
                 datalength(pattern))  as firstpart
from tessst
)X;
```

Comment: great, I would need more sum of the numbers without the character x

Comment: @AdiT do you want only numbers and not X?? eg 120x9x90x80 for this you want 120 9 90 80??

Comment: I want the sum of these numbers you have entered . thanks