# Get maximum value in a column in sql query if the column is alphanumeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, sql-order-by

This is the table which I have by name project and it contains 3 columns:

1. estimateId
2. name
3. projectName

I want to fetch data from SQL database based on maximum value of `estimateId`
but here `estimateid` is alphanumeric. How can I achieve this.

I need a SQL query to achieve this:

For example `estimateId` contains values like:

```
Elooo1
Elooo2
......      
Elooo10
```

and so on. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? The version of the database product may also be a useful information.

Comment: I just started `SQL` like today.. so i'm totally a newbie, but I think I could solve your problem. I would do something like this `SELECT name, projectName FROM table ORDER BY estimateId ASC`  or  `SELECT name, projectName FROM table ORDER BY estimateId DESC`  read up on `ORDER BY` command   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: i am using Microsoft sql server management studio 2017 version

Answer (score 1):

**Setup Testing Data**

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE ( estimateId NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT into @tmpTable(estimateId) VALUES ('Elooo1'),('Elooo2'),('Elooo3'),('Elooo4'),('Elooo5'),('Elooo6');
```

**Split data based on the pattern**

```
SELECT T.prefix AS prefix, MAX(T.suffix) AS suffix, MAX(estimateId) AS estimateId FROM (SELECT estimateId,LEFT(estimateId, PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]%', estimateId )) AS prefix,LTRIM(RIGHT(estimateId, LEN(estimateId) - PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]%', estimateId ))) As suffix FROM @tmpTable) T GROUP BY T.prefix
```

**Result**

```
prefix  suffix  estimateId
Elooo   6   Elooo6
```

**Reference**

[split alpha and numeric using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010295/split-alpha-and-numeric-using-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I just started `SQL` like today.. so i'm totally a newbie, but I think I could solve your problem. I would do something like this

`SELECT name, projectName FROM table ORDER BY estimateId ASC`

or  (I think you will need `ORDER BY ... DESC`)

`SELECT name, projectName FROM table ORDER BY estimateId DESC`

Comment: This would put `'Elooo2'` *after* `'Elooo10'`, which is likely not what OP wants.

Comment: sorry I didn't know, ya it got the number bug.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking to extract the numeric part of the strings. Assuming that the strings have variable length, and that the numbers are always at the end, you can do:

```
try_cast(
    substring(estimateId, patindex('%[0-9]%', estimateId), len(estimateId)) 
    as int
)
```

This captures everything from the the first number in the string to the end of the string, and attempts to convert it to a number (if the conversion fails, `try_cast()` returns `null` rather than raising an error).

It is not very clear what you want to use this information for. For example, if you wanted to sort your data accordingly, you would do:

```
select *
from mytable
order by try_cast(
    substring(estimateId, patindex('%[0-9]%', estimateId), len(estimateId)) 
    as int
)
```